# Better/simpler control flow for: if A, elif B, if A or B, else

Tags: python, if-statement, controls, execution

I have the following control flow and I feel it can be improved but I lack the idea on how to...

I have two MUTUALLY EXCLUSIVE conditions and corresponding actions that need to be done condition specific (i.e. when that one is true) and condition unspecific (i.e. when either is true). Also I want to do something when neither condition is matched.

originally I had:

```py
if condition1:
    print("something only on condition1")
    print("also this because any condition is True")
elif condition2:
    print("something only on condition2")
    print("also this because any condition is True")
else:
    print("do this when no condition")
```

however when the "print("also this because any condition is True")"-part is some large code block it seems impractical to repeat it. Thus I came up with

```py
if condition1:
    print("something only on condition1")
elif condition2:
    print("something only on condition2")
if condition1 or condition2:
    print("also this because any condition is True")
else:
    print("do this when no condition")
```

this however feels somewhat overkill. Since both conditions have already been checked individually, the condition with the "or" statement seems unnecessarily redundant. I might be mistaken though.

An third alternative would be

```py
if condition1 or condition2:
    if condition1:
        print("something only on condition1")
    elif condition2:
        print("something only on condition2")
    print("also this because any condition is True")
else:
    print("do this when no condition")
```

however this is also no real improvement and I feel that the stacked if statements are even harder to comprehend fast.

Also I need to keep in mind that I want the "also this because any condition is True" to be run after any of the condition specific actions.

My goal/question is if there is a smart way to simplify this control flow and to make it easily understood. For example a way to only have 3 control blocks (if, elif, else) or in general to only evaluate each individual condition once.

Thank you :)

**EDIT:**
Background info on the actual task (still simplified):

there are two sets (that might be larger in the future):

```
img_extensions = ('.png', '.jpg')
video_extensions = ('.avi')
```

I now get some path [string] and want to check if either

```
path.endswith(img_extensions)      <- condition1
path.endswith(video_extensions)    <- condition2
```

I then create a video or image according to the condition that is met.
If either is true I tell the user that it was successful.
If no condition was met, the path was faulty and I want to inform the user accordingly.

Comment: If these are complex conditions that you don't want to keep executing, you could just extract them into variables

Comment: good point, however for my case the conditions are actually not too complex so the issues arises more from the pursuit for optimality/perfection

Comment: I think you already gave all the options. As far as I know there's no other option. Pick the one you think is the best.

Comment: @pcsso could you explain those conditions ? It may exist a better alternative depending on them

Comment: you can put "some large code block it seems impractical to repeat it" in a function and use the first block as its the most readable.

Comment: As a follow up to @Masoud, I'm guessing also the parts for condition1 and condition2 are big code blocks. I would put each one in a function, and make that function call the general one Masoud suggested

Comment: @CorentinLimier i added some background info

Comment: @Masoud ha yea, that is quite readable indeed. Defnitly a solution worth considering :)

Answer (score 1):

here is the way i would do that:

```
conditions = {
    condition1: lambda: print("something only on condition1"),
    condition2: lambda: print("something only on condition2")
}

for condition, action in conditions.items():
    if condition:
        action()

if any(conditions.keys()):
    print('also this because any condition is True')
else:
    print('do this when no condition')
```

with this way you can extend your data structure to have lot of condition wihout  editing your logic, also its remove duplication

Comment: very interesting! While the complexity remains largely the same I really like the added flexibility.

Comment: Only downside is that the data structure is static. Meaning, if condition1 changed, it will not change inside the dictionary

Comment: You can put a reference to a dynamic object into the datastructure to solve that

Comment: actually it has to be a dynamic object and not boolean value. Since there can only be 2 boolean keys...

Comment: yes, you have to write your condition somewhere, write it one time and use reference to it everywhere in your programme where you want the same condition, then if you edit your condition the new one will be used everywhere